# Hiccups in exporting data to Excel from Notepad

Tags: excel

I have text in a notepad like below.

```
UserGroupId = 61e65be5-d086-4840-85ac-490cad5d6f6e
Name = Access Care Universal
Description = Assignment group for FDR 3972
EventAssignment = true
LdapAutoAssignment = false

UserGroupId = e61e1255-2d2a-43aa-b221-8182a76204dc
Name = Application Owners
Description = [Empty]
EventAssignment = true
LdapAutoAssignment = false

UserGroupId = ece84749-bb13-4214-83fd-7de4d9782b93
Name = ApplicationOwnersLDAP
Description = [Empty]
EventAssignment = true
LdapAutoAssignment = false

UserGroupId = 138b0cd2-0542-4205-9a6a-b0fea81e3ed6
Name = BBMSupport
Description = OTSS application group
EventAssignment = true
LdapAutoAssignment = false

UserGroupId = 43537523-4595-43fa-8eea-7e8bdacb34e3
Name = BELLCANMO
Description = OTSS application group
EventAssignment = true
LdapAutoAssignment = false

UserGroupId = 70865114-8d3d-4432-8ed0-0c4bc75843ba
Name = BlueprintsInfinite
Description = OTSS application group
EventAssignment = true
LdapAutoAssignment = false
```

I want the data to be converted into an Excel sheet like shown in the below image. [Above data and below image doesn't represent the same values of data]

[image]

For understanding, I have posted a data sample here, but I got a Few MB Text file with the same type of values and doing it manually will be a nightmare.

Does anyone have any ideas?

FYI... I am using Office 365 Desktop Version.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is certainly possible with some combination of PowerQuery to read the file (or text import wizard), then either judicious copy + transpose as  `@w. roby jr` points out in their answer, or some `Index+Match`/ Array formulae to pick out the relevant data by headings into columns. Incidentally, the table in the image only seems to be showing those UserGroups for which `Description <> [Empty]` - is that what you're after?

Comment: You can do this easily with Power Query. What have you tried? BTW,This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with complex formulas or code you are trying to develop. To better understand how this forum works, I suggest you start by taking the [2-minute tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then edit your question to provide information to better enable us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If the data set is relatively small, Copy and Paste into Excel, then Delimit by "=", then Copy and Transpose, then move the columns over.